# New to Magento, Experienced in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am in talks with the company I work at about starting to sell our products online and being the in house web developer I'm stuck with the decision making. I have done a medium amount of research on the pros and cons of a lot of the popular e-commerce sites and figured I'd just go to the forum with my problem.

I am very experienced in Wordpress and have come to get used to it's dynamic functionality. I have heard that Magento is also a very cusomizable platform and CMS but have never used it. I know I can get the hang of it as I've used a lot of different CMS in the past but how is it for end users? Would it be easy for me to teach my 50-60 year old co workers to use the back-end?

tldr; Are my wordpress skills transferrable to Magento?

Answer (score 1):

So I would say I'm fairly qualified to answer this having deployed several hundred Magento stores, where there is a more "mature" content/administrative team and where WP has been deployed alongside Magento.

As a rule, we stray from tuition, as we are developers and speak in riddles, as far as laymen are concerned. So I can't comment on peoples ability to be taught, but I can on peoples ability to self teach.

Without doubt, those that have never used a CMS before seem to pick up WordPress almost instantly, without any further assistance. Magento on the other hand is nowhere near as intuitive. To the educated, you can steer through Magento without issue, but to the uninitiated, its a minefield of orange buttons and tabs.

In at least 5 projects, we've remade the interface for product addition and fulfillment to make the process far simpler and more sensible (per the customers request).

If you have a low labour turnover, you may find yourself spending 4 days teaching and never again. But if you have a high staff turnover, that 4 days might be better invested reinventing the flow of the admin to make it more intuitive and remove the need (and expense) for tuition in the future.

---

From a developer standpoint. WordPress is nothing like Magento. You are moving from a mess of procedural code to an elegant, structured (probably overly so) HMVC framework.

Almost nothing from your WordPress education (other than a basic understanding of PHP) will be transferable.

---

Don't be daunted if I've terrified you, Magento is fantastic, just learn it right from the start and don't develop bad habits (read: hacks).

Answer (score 0):

I have just finished building our first Magento site and we are very happy with our choice. We use the [FishPig](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/integrated-search/) extension to integrate WP for greater flexibility. Magento is a heavy program and getting a very quick site takes some work. To be honest we are still working on it. But it is the right choice for us. You will not have a problem training your employees how to use this. If you do you would have a problem teaching them anything. I have trained my entire staff and the youngest is 49.